# Show the existence of family of sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> Show that there exists a family with cardinality of $c$, of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, such that an intersection of any three elements of the family is an infinite (countable) set and the intersection of any four elements of the family is a finite set.

Other than the fact that set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, I couldn't come up with a way to start. I suppose that such family should be constructed, possibly using set $\mathbb{Q}$, which would then imply that the statement is true for $\mathbb{N}$. Any ideas on how to solve this are welcome.

**Edit**
Malady suggested in the comments that i try constructing four sets such that the given statement is true for them, which is what I did. 
So first I'll define four sets $A=\mathbb{N}$, $B=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, $C=\{\frac{2}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N},\gcd(2,n)\}$ and $D=\{\frac{3}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N},\gcd(3,n)\}$. Four sets satisfying the conditions from the statement are:
$$A\cup B\cup C$$
$$A\cup B\cup D$$
$$A\cup D\cup C$$
$$D\cup B\cup C$$
This suggests that we can, possibly, construct such family by defining some countable subsets of a countable set and then constructing the elements of the family as some union of those subsets. But I'm not sure how to generalize this so that the family is uncountable.

Comment: If this statement is true, then there is certainly an example of size $4$. Ie. there is a collection of 4 sets with this property. See if you can just find that? I’m not sure though.

Comment: @Malady it's easy enough to come up with an example of size $4$ by simply drawing a Venn diagram and putting in the necessary cardinalities in each region.

Comment: @RyanTay: how do you draw a Venn diagram of an uncountable set of sets?

Comment: @RobArthan I merely meant to respond to Malady's comment to illustrate how finding an example with $4$ sets doesn't really help with finding an example which OP asked for

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: The problem is that you can't necessarily actually form the full set that would be each Venn diagram circle and maintain the almost disjointness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will define a family of infinite subsets of the countably infinite set $M=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}M_n$ where $M_n$ is the set of all $3\times n$ matrices of $0$s and $1$s; namely, the family $\{X_a:a\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb N\}$ where
$$X_a=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{A\in M_n:\text{ some row of }A\text{ is an initial segment of }a\}\subseteq M.$$
If $a,b,c,d$ are four distinct infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s, then $X_a\cap X_b\cap X_c$ is an infinite subset of $M$ but $X_a\cap X_b\cap X_c\cap X_d$ is finite.

$X_a\cap X_b\cap X_c$ is infinite because, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, there is a $3\times n$ matrix whose first row is an initial segment of $a$, whose second row is an initial segment of $b$, and whose third row is an initial segment of $c$.

For some $N\in\mathbb N$ the $N^\text{th}$ initial segments of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all different. Hence $X_a\cap X_b\cap X_c\cap X_d\subseteq\bigcup_{n\lt N}M_n$ which is finite.

**More generally,** for any positive integer $k$ we can construct a family $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ with $|\mathcal A|=\mathfrak c$ such that the intersection of any $k$ elements of $\mathcal A$ is infinite while the intersection of any $k+1$ elements of $\mathcal A$ is finite.